# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Dropbox icon systray

Tags: dropbox, 22.04, system-tray

After vanilla installation of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS I have noticed 2 related issues with the icon in the systray.

For clarity, the client was installed from Ubuntu Software, following the usual methodologies for set up.

The first issue is that the icon is not persistent. After a while, the usual "stacked box" icon transforms in to a 3 horizontal dot icon. If left to it's own devices, after a while it returns as it should be but some time later it transforms again. There appears to be no detectable reason for this behaviour.

The second connected issue is that with either icon in place in the systray, selecting the icon with a mouse click (either left or right) the menu presented includes as normal the option to Launch Dropbox Website.

On my 20.04.4 LTS system, that works correctly in that it does indeed launch the home page of my Dropbox account but on 22.04 LTS it attempts to launch `file://tmp/dbox/` followed by a long string of letters and numbers which Firefox errors with `File not found`.

**The questions**

In the case of the first issue (changing icon) is there a way of rendering the correct icon persistent?

In the case of the second, is there a way of editing the address to which the menu option refers?

Comment: I have the same problem with the Dropbox icon in 22.04.

Comment: @heynnema both issues?

Comment: Icon yes. Launch no.

Comment: @heynnema hummm  The launch has been corrupted somehow. Thanks.

Comment: Check your "Default Applications" in settings panel.

Comment: @heynnema Web = Firefox. No other configuration for Dropbox. If you are referring to Applications, there are no options for Dropbox other than Notifications set on.

Comment: Web=Firefox is where you want it... but just in case it's internal settings are screwed up, change it to Chrome, then change it back to Firefox, and see if that fixes your problem #2.

Comment: @heynnema nice idea, but no change to the behaviour sadly. Even leaving it at Chromium doesn't have an effect. It still goes to FF 

Comment: Well, there's the lead that you have to follow. I don't have a clue though where to look. Sorry.

Comment: @heynnema resolved the FF issue... it was the snap version of FF which was causing the issue. I followed the instructions [here](https://fostips.com/ubuntu-21-10-two-firefox-remove-snap/) installing the deb version and the Dropbox drop down menu now correctly selects the correct web page. Only remaining issue is the transforming icon.

Comment: Darn snaps. Thanks for the update. Good job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue of the Dropbox drop down menu selecting the wrong web page has now been resolved by removing FF snap and installing the .deb version in its place using the instructions set out in this FOSTips article which specifically addresses Ubuntu 22.04 LTS:

https://fostips.com/ubuntu-21-10-two-firefox-remove-snap/

Following these instructions version 100.0 was installed (as at 10th May 2022).

1. Remove Firefox snap
2. Install the classic Firefox deb package
3. Add the PPA and set the PPA priority
4. Install Firefox from PPA

A further advantage of the .deb version is that it also allowed the installation of the GNOME browser extensions avoiding this message which appears on the snap version.

[image]