# After upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04.1 to 22.04.1 flatpak package dropbox malfunctioning

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, dropbox

So, I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04.1 to 22.04.1 I have the flatpack Dropbox app installed. It is because the version dropbox officially provides is never up to date with the latest Ubuntu version.

But now my dropbox icon appears but putting my cursor over it and clicking does nothing. The app has gone dead after the upgrade. I attached a screenshot.

[image]

So can the flatpack package be repaired or do I need to uninstall it and install dropbox from a different source? Thank you.

Comment: The version from Ubuntu Software v2019.02.14 (ubuntu-jammy-multiverse (deb) does work, the only problem I had with it was the `dropbox` icon occasionally disappearing and being replaced with a 3 horizontal dot icon which when clicked did work. The only other issue was the `Launch Dropbox Website` didn't render properly but that was fixed by having a bookmark to `www.dropbox.com/h` in your browser. Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407189/ubuntu-22-04-lts-dropbox-icon-systray

Comment: Also, since the number of users is restricted under the free plan to 3, log in to the web app directly as indicated and ensure that you have not used up all your allowed accesses.

Comment: So I uninstalled dropbox faltpak package and instead installed the Ubuntu repository package

Comment: does that now work for you?

Comment: @24601 yes it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So can the flatpack package be repaired or do I need to uninstall it
> and install dropbox from a different source?

The version from Ubuntu Software v2019.02.14 (ubuntu-jammy-multiverse (deb) does work, the only problem I had with it was the dropbox icon occasionally disappearing and being replaced with a 3 horizontal dot icon which when clicked did work although as of 22.04.1 release that issue persists. The only other issue was the Launch Dropbox Website didn't render properly in the browser address bar but that was fixed by having a bookmark to [www.dropbox.com/h](http://www.dropbox.com/h) in your browser and also still persists.

See also my question and related answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407189/ubuntu-22-04-lts-dropbox-icon-systray)

Other than those two points, the `Dropbox` deb application functions as intended.